# CSS Grid row issue

Tags: html, css, css-grid

```css
buy-page {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  position: relative;
  grid-auto-rows: 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 200px;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<main class="buy-page">
  <div class="buy-1 buy">
    <img src="../picsfolder/BUY-1.jpg" alt=""> </div>

  <div class="buy-2 buy">
    <img src="../picsfolder/buy02.jpg" alt=""> </div>

  <div class="buy-3 buy">
    <img src="../picsfolder/SOLD-1.jpg" alt=""> </div>
</main>
```

Hi, I am trying to figure out buy-1 goes to the second row.

here is my code,

there are 3 pictures, the first picture can go to the second column with grid-column: span 3;

however, when I am tring buy-1 {grid-row-start:1; grid-row-end:3;} nothing happens.

Would you tell me how to make the buy-1 stretch to the second row, please?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure i fully understand what you are trying to achieve here but
make sure you're referencing your class correctly with `.buy` instead of `buy-page`

```
.buy {   
  display: grid;   
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);  
  position: relative;   
  grid-auto-rows: 1fr;   
  grid-template-rows: 200px;   
  grid-gap: 10px;   
  width: 200px;   
  height: 400px; 
}
```